# Self hosted web api не возвращает ничего

Tags: c#, mono, asp.net-web-api

Возникла очень странная проблема :
После запуска self hosted web api под mono - первый запрос проходит успешно, а последующие - "зависают". С помощью отладки было выяснено что действие в контроллере вызывается, ответ возвращается из действия, но не более. Есть мысль, что виснет вебсокет, который использует `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.SelfHost`. Как это можно победить?

P.S. Под Windows все работает отлично.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Гугл ничего не дал. По этому перешел на Owin Self Host. Полет отличный.

P.S. Лучше обновить mono до версии 4.0.1